# Category clustering in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, categories

#### context: creation of a CMS

I am looking for an effective way to represent subject nesting/dependance of articles in a Django model. Right now, **Categories** are defined as follow:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent        = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name='nested_category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name          = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    nesting_level = models.IntegerField(default = 0, editable=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(Category, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.parent != None:
            self.nesting_level = self.parent.nesting_level + 1
        elif self.parent == None:
            self.nesting_level = 0

    def __str__(self):                           
        full_path = [self.name.lower()]                                        
        k = self.parent                          

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.name.lower())
            k = k.parent

        return '->'.join(full_path[::-1])
```

This works pretty well. Every time a category is added, `nesting_level` is calculated based on the parent's `nesting_level`. I see the changes in the BDD (I know, one should not override `__init__` in Django but I'll come to this issue later).

#### The need

Say I have the following category three:

```
Code--------Python---------Django
 [1]    |     [2]     |      [3]
        |             |----Functional_Programing
        |---Java               [5]
             [4]
```

When hitting for the category **Python**, the view should not only present **Articles** in

- `code->python` but also
- `code->python->django`
- `code->python->functional_programing`

since the latter are also *python related*. When hiting on the url `/browse/code->python/` the view would say something like `articles = Article.objects.filter(category__in=[2, 3, 5])`

#### The idea that does not work (And I am not sure why)

Since categories are not changed quite often, I thought that it would be a good idea to **represent this three structure in the BDD itself** in order to easily extract the list of children subjects. The table would look something like:

```
id | name                  | nesting_level | cluster | parent
1  | Code                  | 0             | 1,2,3,5 | None
2  | Python                | 1             | 2,3,5   | 1
3  | Django                | 2             | 3       | 2
4  | Java                  | 1             | 4       | 1
5  | Functional_programing | 3             | 5       | 2
```

The **Category** class, slightly modified:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent        = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name='nested_category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name          = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    nesting_level = models.IntegerField(default = 0, editable=False)
    cluster       = models.CharField(default = "", max_length=20, editable=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(Category, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.cluster = str(self.id)
        if self.parent != None:
            self.nesting_level = self.parent.nesting_level + 1
            self.parent.cluster = "{},{}".format(self.parent.cluster,self.id)
        elif self.parent == None:
            self.nesting_level = 0
```

It seems to work when I `print` but changes does not seem to append in the BDD (at this early stage of development: an **SLQlite**). I read that `__init__` should not be override in Django for related '*signal reasons*' so I also tried to override `save` instead:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cluster = str(self.id)
        if self.parent != None:
            self.nesting_level = self.parent.nesting_level + 1
            self.parent.cluster = "{},{}".format(self.parent.cluster,self.id)
        elif self.parent == None:
            self.nesting_level = 0
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

which does not work either but, this time, because `self.id=None(<class 'NoneType'>)`.

I am starting to feel a bit lost in the subtleties of this ORM. Since there is probably more straightforward ways to achieve what I am looking for but I am also interested in understanding why my approach does not work, **all kind of advices are welcome**.

Comment: Sorry for not engaging with the actual code but hierarchical relationship modelling is a deep topic, have you browsed [this page](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/trees-and-graphs/) of Django packages? Solving these problems is why those packages exist - one of them might fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander . [this one](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) seems promising